# Navigation Div Affecting Other Nav Elements

Tags: html, navigation, sass, css

I have several div elements acting as a main navigation. When a page is active, I have a separate div element for each so that the height of the div is higher. This seems to affect the line height/position of the other divs on the page for some reason.

Here is my SASS

```
#neo_mainnav {  /* Main navigation */
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 35px;
        width: 480px;

        .nav_text {
            font: 14pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            line-height: 35px;
        }

        #video_nav {
            float: left;
            margin-right: 10px;
            width: 112.50px;
            height: 35px;
            background: #66a9c6;
        }

        #video_nav_active {
            float: left;
            margin-right: 10px;
            width: 112.50px;
            height: 50px;
            background: #66a9c6;
        }

        #gallery_nav {
            float: left;
            margin-right: 10px; 
            width: 112.50px;
            height: 35px;
            background: #f0a262;
        }

        #gallery_nav_active {
            float: left;
            margin-right: 10px;
            width: 112.50px;
            height: 75px;
            background: #f0a262;
        }

        #floorplans_nav {
            float: left;
            margin-right: 10px;
            width: 112.50px;
            height: 35px;
            background: #66a9c6;
        }

        #floorplans_nav_active {
            float: left;
            margin-right: 10px;
            width: 112.50px;
            height: 75px;
            background: #66a9c6;
        }

        #contact_nav {
            float: left;
            width: 112.50px;
            height: 35px;
            background: #f0a262;
        }

        #contact_nav_active {
            float: left;
            width: 112.50px;
            height: 35px;
            background: #f0a262;
        }
    }   /* Main navigation end */
```

The HTML can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/MQcGF/

The entire page can be viewed here http://www.neoscapelabs.com/projects/469seventh/gallery.php

Comment: Please also post your pertinent HTML.

Comment: My mistake, I've added a JSFiddle that goes to my HTML. It can also be viewed at the site I linked below that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently, and I solved it by assigning a (higher) z-index to the 'active' states/classes. It worked for me.
Just in case, to avoid the same struggle I had; remember that z-indexing only works on positioned elements.